# How to add a hyperlink to a URL in groff with mom macros?

Tags: text-processing, groff

How can I create a hyperlink to a URL in groff, using the mom macros?

I know it is possible to create links to other sections within the same document, but I want to know how to create a clickable hyperlink to a webpage in groff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mom macro `PDF_WWW_LINK`:

```
.PDF_WWW_LINK https://example.com "the link"
```

This seems to be documented in the `mom-pdf.pdf` file, but in my Fedora distribution the file is empty, but there are the sources: [mom-pdf.mom](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/groff-1.22.4.tar.gz/groff-1.22.4/contrib/mom/examples/mom-pdf.mom?m=t).